# Could I do this with d3.js delauany?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Thanks for this superb lib.

I have some  doubts.
First, could I build a d3.version focused in geo / geom features? Could it be possible under the d3.js license? Could it be technically easy?  (The goal : have a lower size lib)
Second, I would like to know if it is easy to implement :
- Closed global polyline.
- Holes (or delete triangles contained by a closed polyline ) 
- Forced edges (Hard lines that cant't be crossed by any triangle edge).

Thanks.

Comment: Customising D3 isn't that hard and not a licensing issue -- what you then use it for may be an issue. As for your other questions, all of these can be implemented.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff , what do you wnat to say with : "what you then use it for may be an issue"??

Comment: The license doesn't prevent you from modifying the code in any way. One of the things it doesn't allow you to do is for example to then claim that the entire thing is your own work.